# Unknown column in 'where clause' bash script for mysql

Tags: mysql, bash

This is my console command (first line) and output:

```
source request.sh a a "ZP07"
a a ZP07
USE intro_ict; SELECT idbuildings from buildings WHERE address = ZP07;
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
the tables in the database are: buildings
room
sensordata
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'ZP07' in 'where clause'
the selected building ZP07 has idbuilding
```

and this is request.sh:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2
  3 #args = startdate ($1) enddate ($2) address($3) roomnr($4)
  4 echo "$1 $2 $3 $4"
  5
  6 sql1="USE intro_ict; SELECT idbuildings from buildings WHERE address = $3;"
  7 tables="USE intro_ict; SHOW TABLES;"
  8 echo "$sql1"
  9
 10 echo "the tables in the database are: $(mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -padmin -se "$tables")"
 11 idbuilding=$(mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -padmin -se "USE intro_ict; SELECT idBuildings FROM Buildings WHERE (address = $3);")
 12
 13 echo "the selected building $3 has idbuilding $idbuilding"
 14 #mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -padmin -se "USE intro_ict; SELECT * FROM buildings;"
 15
 16
```

I want to use a bash script to display data from a mysql database to the console. I looked at other solutions for this problem (using different quotes ("", '', ``) but nothing works. I'm using ubuntu for windows and I can see in mysqlworkbench that the column buildings.address is definitely there.

I don't know what to try anymore.

Comment: Please remove line numbers from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause in question:

```
WHERE address = ZP07
```

Says to look for a column named `address` that is equal to another column named `ZP07`.

I'm guessing:

- `ZP07` is actually a **value** stored in the `address` column and ...
- there is no column in the table named `ZP07` which ...
- explains the error message: `Unknown column 'ZP07'`

To address this issue what you want to do is place single quotes around the `ZP07` value, eg:

```
WHERE address = 'ZP07'
```

Which can be accomplished by adding the single quotes around `$3` in your shell script, eg:

```
sql1="USE intro_ict; SELECT idbuildings from buildings WHERE address = '$3';"

# and

idbuilding=$(mysql ... "USE intro_ict; SELECT idBuildings FROM Buildings WHERE (address = '$3');")
```

**NOTE**: OP may want to reconsider rewriting the `idbuilding=$(mysql...)` portion to make use of the `sql1` variable so that the `SELECT` statement doesn't have to be maintained in 2x different locations, eg:

```
idbuilding=$(mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -padmin -se "${sql1}")
```